# How can I get Roman numerals in text?

Tags: roman-numerals

For example:

> Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip VI of France, the future John II of France, in 1335.

How can I get Roman numerals?

Comment: Simply write "Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip VI of France, the future John II of France, in 1335."

Comment: Indeed, simply write it as you did. Doesn't this work for you? If so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Maybe it's a font issue or similar.

Comment: If you want over- and underlined roman numerals, please see the answer to this question: [Roman numerals formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24065/6865)

Comment: Not all fonts make distinguishable Roman numerals, or nice letters 'I', 'V', 'X'. 
For that reason, I usually use \textrm{XXIV}.

Answer (score 75):

Here's an example how you could use the TeX primitive (mentioned by Martin) for defining your own macro for conversion to big Roman numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip \rom{6} of France,
the future John \rom{2} of France, in 1335.

Today is the year \rom{2011}.
\end{document}
```

[image: roman numbers]

It's done similar to the definition of the LaTeX macro `\Roman`.

Comment: Any idea why the LaTeX kernel doesn't use `\uppercase` here?

Comment: `\uppercase` doesn't expand the argument, so it would not have an effect here. However, `\MakeUppercase` would do it.

Comment: I know but this can be fixed with `\expandafter`: `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral<number>\relax}`. Works fine in my quick tests.

Comment: Perhaps since only a few characters need to be capitalized, so just a few decisions but not regarding arguments from a complete alphabet. source2e did not tell it.

Comment: @Martin: Try the different approaches inside an `\edef`, and see why `\uppercase` is not going to work. (I think the actual application was in `\csname`, but the same idea applies.)

Comment: @Joseph: Oh, yes, of course! I didn't thought about `\edef` context. My bad.

Comment: @Martin If the kernel had defined `\Roman` as `\def\@Roman#1{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}`, it would be OK for `\label` and `\ref`, but one could not do manipulations to the obtained strings, which instead can be done with the result from the slower routine.

Comment: @egreg: Why isn't there a `\Romannumeral`? Did D.E.Knuth not like uppercase roman numerals?

Comment: @Martin I don't know; actually `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral<number>}` works well; the main use of `\romannumeral` is, I think, in `\csname` (think to `\@enumctr`), so an uppercase version is unimportant.

Comment: @Stephan: how did your `\rom{6}` render as `XXV` (and was there ever a Philip XXV of France)?

Comment: I think uppercase roman numeral look nicer with a tighter kerning to merge the serifs. How would you do that?

Comment: @Raphink: I made the screenshot a bit later, inbetween I just checked if higher numbers are correctly displayed. I corrected the screenshot.

Comment: @Raphink: Regarding tighter kerning for certain text, it would be good if you post it as a new question, with reference to here.

Comment: Is it possible to make this somehow work in math mode?

Answer (score 49):

The `\romannumeral` kernel primitive is your friend:

```
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}

Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip \RNum{4} of France, the future John \RNum{2} of France, in 1335.
```

Comment: As usual, Martin was 2 minutes earlier :-)

Comment: at first glance (and naive), \uppercase should be preceded (and not succeed) by \expandafter. Why this inversion?

Answer (score 30):

[biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) offers the macros `\RN` and `\Rn` for upper- resp. lowercase roman numerals, plus `\RNfont` and `\Rnfont` for formatting those numerals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\Rnfont}{\scshape}

% The following is only included to prevent BibTeX/biber errors!
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Philip~\RN{6} (or, if you prefer, Philip~\Rn{6})~\dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can convert a number to a lowercase roman numeral using the TeX primitive `\romannumeral<number>\relax`or in uppercase using `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral<number>\relax}`. Counter values can be printed in as Roman numerals using `\roman{<counter>}` (lowercase) and `\Roman{<counter>}` (uppercase).

However for simple Roman numerals in text I would simple write it as you already did.

Answer (score 24):

Simply write

> Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip VI of France,
>   the future John II of France, in 1335.

Comment: It might require calculation for bigger Roman numbers.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't think there were this many Philips and Johns of France :-)

Comment: @Martin: I agree :-)

Comment: Using a macro has the advantage that there's semantics - for example, roman numerals could be changed regarding font or shape later on. That would be hard if common alphabetic letters are used.

Comment: @Stefan: I agree, but Roman numerals (at least in regular text) normally use the same font as the normal text, so I don't see (at least in regular text) any significant advantage.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Just ideas and thoughts. I like macros :-) btw. the OP desired tighter kerning for the Roman numbers I see now.

Comment: @Stefan & Gonzalo: I have to agree with both of you. The question could be (much!) clearer about what the OP exactly wants. Does he wants to have font suggestions or does he really want to convert numbers to roman numerals? ...

Comment: I think I'd use code markup here instead of blockquote.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: That is why I do not use Roman numbers in the first place :-)

Comment: In some cases KISS is the right way. The site really embraces overoptimisation...

Comment: When in Rome...

Answer (score 23):

If you want to enter roman numbers within your text,please follow these instructions.

1. in the first step you have to install the package of "romannum".
2. in this step you have to use this package in your text,therefore type this:

   ```
   \usepackage{romannum}
   ```
3. Now you can write roman numbers in your text in lowercase or uppercase by this command.

- `\romannum{1}` for Lowercase roman numbers or
- `\Romannum{1}` for Uppercase roman numbers.

For example suppose that we want to write this sentence.

> ten million people died between  WWI and WWII.

We write in Latex:

```
ten million people died between WW\Romannum{1} and WW\Romannum{2}.
```

Also, the package changes the page numbering, so to keep it arabic you need to add this line in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\pagenumbering{arabic}}
```

Comment: You should add that the package changes the presentation of all counters to roman. -- From the documentation: "LaTeX generates numbers for things like chapters and sections, figure and table
captions, and page numbers. Normally these are printed using arabic digits. The `romannum` package modifies the typesetting of such generated numbers so that they are printed as roman numerals."

Comment: When using \usepackage{romannum}, the page numbering automatically changed to roman numbers(additional to required places). How to keep that normal numbers