# Using unicode Roman numerals in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode, roman-numerals

As mentioned in [How can I get Roman numerals in text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/how-can-i-get-roman-numerals-in-text), there are several ways in which one can add Roman numerals to text in TeX. However, these solutions all seem to use three I's to make a roman numeral 3, rather than combining using the "Number forms" symbols found in many fonts such as "Ⅲ".

Is there a way to get XeTeX to render all of the Roman numerals in a document using the special Roman numeral symbols found in many fonts?

Comment: Please note the Roman numerals in Unicode are compatibility characters, and using ordinary Latin characters to denote Roman numerals is preferred.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Can you show a reference?

Comment: Check section 15.3, p. 486 of [The Unicode Standard, Version 6.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch15.pdf) book; *For most purposes, it is preferable to compose the Roman numerals from sequences of the appropriate Latin letters. However, the uppercase and lowercase variants of the Roman numerals through 12, plus L, C, D, and M, have been encoded for compatibility with East Asian standards.*

Comment: Not a complete duplicate question, but similar to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24065/6865

Comment: I'm quite surprised to see that you think that my answer deals only with small numbers; probably you haven't tried it with larger ones.

Comment: @egreg: I guess that Village might not like the fact that 59 is `D-I-X` rather than `D-IX`. Am I right?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The decomposition of Ⅸ is `<compat> 0049 0058 [ ‌I ‌X ]`, so I don't see a point here; however, writing `ⅮⅨ` (`D-IX`) instead of `ⅮⅠⅩ` (`D-I-X`) might give spacing problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\def\uromannumeral#1{\symbol{\numexpr"216F+#1\relax}}
\def\uRomannumeral#1{\symbol{\numexpr"215F+#1\relax}}
\def\uroman#1{\uromannumeral{\the\value{#1}}}
\def\uRoman#1{\uRomannumeral{\the\value{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\uromannumeral{12} \uRomannumeral{7}

\uroman{page} \uRoman{page}

\def\theenumi{\uRoman{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 14):

```
\makeatletter
\def\UniRoman#1{\expandafter\@UniRoman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\uniroman#1{\expandafter\@uniroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\def\@UniRoman#1{\ifcase#1\or
  Ⅰ\or Ⅱ\or Ⅲ\or Ⅳ\or Ⅴ\or Ⅵ\or Ⅶ\or Ⅷ\or Ⅸ\or Ⅹ\or Ⅺ\or Ⅻ\else
  \expandafter\@slowUniRoman\romannumeral #1@\fi}
\def\@slowUniRoman#1{\ifx @#1% then terminate
     \else
       \if i#1Ⅰ\else\if v#1Ⅴ\else\if x#1Ⅹ\else\if
       l#1Ⅼ\else\if c#1Ⅽ\else\if d#1Ⅾ\else \if
       m#1Ⅿ\else#1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
       \expandafter\@slowUniRoman
     \fi
}
\def\@uniroman#1{\ifcase#1\or
  ⅰ\or ⅱ\or ⅲ\or ⅳ\or ⅴ\or ⅵ\or ⅶ\or ⅷ\or ⅸ\or ⅹ\or ⅺ\or ⅻ\else
  \expandafter\@slowuniroman\romannumeral #1@\fi}
\def\@slowuniroman#1{\ifx @#1% then terminate
     \else
       \if i#1ⅰ\else\if v#1ⅴ\else\if x#1ⅹ\else\if
       l#1ⅼ\else\if c#1ⅽ\else\if d#1ⅾ\else \if
       m#1ⅿ\else#1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
       \expandafter\@slowuniroman
     \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{cnta}
\renewcommand{\thecnta}{\uniroman{cnta}} % lowercase Roman numerals
\newcounter{cntb}
\renewcommand{\thecnta}{\UniRoman{cntb}} % uppercase Roman numerals
```

It's up to you to decide that `\roman` and `\@roman` become, respectively, `\uniroman` and `\@uniroman` (similarly for the uppercase variant).

These macros allow for representing any positive integer with the Roman number system. If one wants to use also "ↁ", "ↂ", "ↇ", and "ↈ", then some more work is needed.

### Added

Support for the extended numerals can be obtained in a quite straigthforward way:

```
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\makeatletter
\def\extUniRoman#1{\expandafter\@extUniRoman\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\def\@extUniRoman#1{%
  \expandafter\@slowhighUniRoman\romannumeral\bigintcalcDiv{\number#1}{1000}@%
  \expandafter\@slowUniRoman\romannumeral\bigintcalcMod{\number#1}{1000}@}
\def\@slowhighUniRoman#1{\ifx @#1% then terminate
     \else
       \if i#1ↀ\else\if v#1ↁ\else\if x#1ↂ\else\if
       l#1ↇ\else\if c#1ↈ\else\if d#1ↈↈↈↈↈ\else \if
       m#1ↈↈↈↈↈↈↈↈↈↈ\else#1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
       \expandafter\@slowhighUniRoman
     \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Just to make an example, with

```
\newcounter{cntc}
\renewcommand{\thecntc}{\extUniRoman{cntc}}
\setcounter{cntc}{792409}
\thecntc
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Oh, I've never seen roman numerals like ↁ

Comment: Neither have I, but it seems that they were used in some cases. The ↀ form for 1000 was rather common, actually.

Comment: That's funny. Now the solution is suitable for generic usage, maybe it can be exported as a package or merge into some package?

Comment: Probably with some options to decide which kind of roman numeral is used.

Answer (score 7):

The free (Open Font License) font [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) automatically turns "spelled out" Roman numerals from `I` to `XII` (both uppercase and lowercase) into their Unicode counterparts if you activate discretionary ligatures (`dlig`). It works just like `f` and `l` are combined to the ﬂ ligature in the output.

Pros:

- no additional code necessary when you're writing
- awesome free font, not only, but especially for Medievalists

Cons:

- numbers like XIII look strange because they're rendered as XII+I
  <sub>This really is a problem on Unicode's side though, because Unicode only has Roman numbers up to 12. Then again, I guess Junicode could've kept going and added more numerals as ligatures in the private area usage area of Unicode.</sub>
- you may not want all the ligatures in your document that are included in `dlig`
  <sub>For the latter problem, Mico's upcoming `selnolig` package might be useful, which allows you to globally disable a specific ligature with a single macro, all using LuaTeX. Stay tuned.</sub>

Here's a document showing some of Junicode's discretionary ligatures:

```
% compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures={Discretionary}]{Junicode}
    % Naturally, I'd also enable "TeX" and "Common" ligatures
    % when using discretionary ligatures
    % I dare you to check out Junicode's historical ligatures!
    % http://junicode.sourceforge.net/Junicode.pdf#page=13

\textwidth=4cm % These two lines are just
\parindent=0cm % to keep my example compact

\begin{document}

i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii, viii, ix, x, xi, xii

I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, XI, XII

{\Huge XIII} % That ain't pretty

Ⅼ, Ⅽ, Ⅾ, Ⅿ, ↀ, ↁ, ↂ % These are (all?) other Unicode Roman numerals Junicode has
                         % (which have nothing to do with dlig though)

tt, tr, tty % These are some presumably acceptable discretionary ligatures of Junicode

ct, hv, st % These are the weird ligatures in dlig

[7], [[4]], <13>, [g], [W] % These are also part of dlig, but probably not bothersome

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What would be the relationship between Discretionary and Rare?  I have to choose one or the other, or would Discretionary include Rare?

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard, but you could either just play around and try to find out, or have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75720/4012