# Roman Number Symbols

Tags: symbols, roman-numerals

I am looking for a latex package which supports roman number symbols. Particularly [alternative / ancient roman symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Pre-Roman.2FAncient_Rome) should be included in this package.

To be more precise, I currently need a symbol for thousand which looks like "(I)" or "CIↃ".

Comment: If a font does not provide `CIↃ` it can be generated by `\usepackage{graphics}...CI\reflectbox{C}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this works for my special case. I am still hoping for a more elaborate solution which also incorporates further symbols.

Comment: Perhaps of some relevance: [Using unicode Roman numerals in XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/using-unicode-roman-numerals-in-xetex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unicode with LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX and Linux Libertine

An example with the OpenType font Linux Libertine, tested with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. The characters can be used inside `\textroman` directly by the right Unicode characters or via macros `\textroman...`.

(Update: Using `\encodingdefault` instead of `EU2` to support XeLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\fontlibertine{Linux Libertine O}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textroman}{\fontlibertine}

% Using \encodingdefault, because LuaLaTeX uses EU2 and XeLaTeX EU1
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanOne}{\encodingdefault}{"2160}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanTwo}{\encodingdefault}{"2161}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanThree}{\encodingdefault}{"2162}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanFour}{\encodingdefault}{"2163}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanFive}{\encodingdefault}{"2164}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanSix}{\encodingdefault}{"2165}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanSeven}{\encodingdefault}{"2166}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanEight}{\encodingdefault}{"2167}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanNine}{\encodingdefault}{"2168}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanTen}{\encodingdefault}{"2169}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanEleven}{\encodingdefault}{"216A}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanTwelve}{\encodingdefault}{"216B}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanFifty}{\encodingdefault}{"216C}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanHundred}{\encodingdefault}{"216D}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanFivehundred}{\encodingdefault}{"216E}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanThousand}{\encodingdefault}{"216F}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanone}{\encodingdefault}{"2170}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromantwo}{\encodingdefault}{"2171}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanthree}{\encodingdefault}{"2172}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanfour}{\encodingdefault}{"2173}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanfive}{\encodingdefault}{"2174}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromansix}{\encodingdefault}{"2175}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanseven}{\encodingdefault}{"2176}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromaneight}{\encodingdefault}{"2177}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromannine}{\encodingdefault}{"2178}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanten}{\encodingdefault}{"2179}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromaneleven}{\encodingdefault}{"217A}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromantwelve}{\encodingdefault}{"217B}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanfifty}{\encodingdefault}{"217C}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanhundred}{\encodingdefault}{"217D}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanfivehundred}{\encodingdefault}{"217E}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanthousand}{\encodingdefault}{"217F}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanThousandCD}{\encodingdefault}{"2180}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanFiveThousand}{\encodingdefault}{"2181}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanTenThousand}{\encodingdefault}{"2182}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanCreversed}{\encodingdefault}{"2183}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromancreversed}{\encodingdefault}{"2184}


\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
  \textsf{U+#1}
  & \textsf{\textbackslash textroman#2}
  & \textroman{\csname textroman#2\endcsname}
  & \textroman{\bfseries\csname textroman#2\endcsname}
  & \textroman{\itshape\csname textroman#2\endcsname}
  \tabularnewline
}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\test{2160}{One}   
\test{2161}{Two}   
\test{2162}{Three} 
\test{2163}{Four}   
\test{2164}{Five}   
\test{2165}{Six}    
\test{2166}{Seven}  
\test{2167}{Eight}  
\test{2168}{Nine}   
\test{2169}{Ten}    
\test{216A}{Eleven} 
\test{216B}{Twelve} 
\test{216C}{Fifty}  
\test{216D}{Hundred}
\test{216E}{Fivehundred}
\test{216F}{Thousand}
\test{2170}{one}   
\test{2171}{two}   
\test{2172}{three} 
\test{2173}{four}   
\test{2174}{five}   
\test{2175}{six}    
\test{2176}{seven}  
\test{2177}{eight}  
\test{2178}{nine}   
\test{2179}{ten}    
\test{217A}{eleven} 
\test{217B}{twelve} 
\test{217C}{fifty}  
\test{217D}{hundred}
\test{217E}{fivehundred} 
\test{217F}{thousand}    
\test{2180}{ThousandCD}  
\test{2181}{FiveThousand}
\test{2182}{TenThousand}
\test{2183}{Creversed}
\test{2184}{creversed}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Unsupported:}\\[1ex]
\textsf{U+2185} & roman numeral six late form\\
\textsf{U+2186} & roman numeral fifty early form\\
\textsf{U+2187} & roman numeral fifty thousand\\
\textsf{U+2188} & roman numeral one hundred thousand
\end{tabular}      

\end{document}
```

> [image: Roman numerals with font Linux Libertine]

### Reversed C with `\reflectbox`

`Ↄ` can be generated using `\reflectbox` of package `graphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% or graphics
\usepackage{amstext}

\newcommand*{\textCreversed}{\text{\reflectbox{C}}}

\begin{document}

CI\textCreversed\textsuperscript{CI\textCreversed}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Reversed C with \reflectbox]

Comment: I can not check this right now, but it seems like a good solution. Too bad that this is not part of a package.

Comment: You can also use XeLaTeX, provided EU2 is changed into EU1. You can say `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textromanOne}{\encodingdefault}{"2160}` to make it work for both engines.