# Using ligatures from libertine for roman numerals in pdftex

Tags: ligatures, libertine, roman-numerals

I am using the Linux Libertine font through the libertine-legacy package with pdftex. This font contains nice ligatures for roman numerals, e.g., `\LibertineGlyph{tworoman}` gives ii. Now I want to use those glyphs whereever they occur with counters, e.g., page numbers in frontmatter, and `part` numbering. In the end I would like to have an analogue to `\roman`, say `\ligroman`, that I can feed to `\pagenumberstyle` etc.

Comment: Related: [How does "libertine-type1" work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76305) The “new” `-type1` fonts don't support `\libertineGlyph`. This can be done with either the old `libertine-legacy` package or the Xe-/LuaTeX/OpenType version `libertineotf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## From Ⅰ to Ⅻ

### Libertine and `\libertineGlyph`

*In my example I use XeLaTeX and [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) which provides `\libertineGlyph` and the glyphs. As stated in my comment, this* should *work with [`libertine-legacy`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine-legacy), too. [The new `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1` don't support this anymore.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76305/how-does-libertine-type1-work)*

This provides two macros:

- `\libertineRoman{<countername>}` for majuscle, and
- `\libertineroman{<countername>}` for minuscle Roman digits .

This approach converts only numbers between 1 and 12 into the special roman digit glyphs.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}% replace with libertine-legacy
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% use with pdfLaTeX
\newcommand*{\libertineRoman}[1]{%
    \def\Romantemp{}%
    \ifnum\value{#1}>0\relax%
        \ifnum\value{#1}<13\relax%
            \edef\Romantemp{\ifcase\value{#1}\or One\or Two\or Three\or Four\or Five\or Six\or Seven\or Eight\or Nine\or Ten\or Eleven\or Twelve\fi}%
            \libertineGlyph{\Romantemp roman}%
        \else\Roman{#1}\fi%
    \else\Roman{#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand*{\libertineroman}[1]{%
    \def\Romantemp{}%
    \ifnum\value{#1}>0\relax%
        \ifnum\value{#1}<13\relax%
            \edef\Romantemp{\ifcase\value{#1}\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\fi}%
            \libertineGlyph{\Romantemp roman}%
        \else\roman{#1}\fi%
    \else\roman{#1}\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{testRoman}
\setcounter{testRoman}{13}
\loop\ifnum\value{testRoman}>1\relax\addtocounter{testRoman}{-1}
    \thetestRoman: \roman{testRoman} \Roman{testRoman} \libertineroman{testRoman} \libertineRoman{testRoman} \par
\repeat
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

## Unicode (Xe-/LuaLaTeX only)

A solution that uses the whole range of Unicode's Roman digits is [already available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38695/16595).

Comment: I don't think this answer the question -- the OP explicitly asked for pdfTeX.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel @doncherry I just tried with LaTeX and with pdfLaTeX and libertine legacy (which is in my TEXMFLOCAL `$ kpsewhich libertine.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/libertine-legacy/libertine.sty`) and it works.

Comment: That's it! It works with the `libertine-legacy` package. An answer for (xe|lua)latex can also be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/using-unicode-roman-numerals-in-xetex)

Comment: @doncherry Yes, he did, but as I wrote it should work with a working `libertine-legacy`, too.

Comment: @mafp Were you aware of that other question when you asked yours? Apparently you don't need L, C, D and M? Than I won't pursue another solution …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No, I was not aware of that other question/answer, I just kept browsing after asking. Given that the roman numbers larger than 12 end up in a different size I will use your solution only when the counters stay below 13, so there is no need for C, D, M.