# Using ligatures from Linux Libertine for numbering sections and in TOC

Tags: fonts, sectioning, ligatures, libertine

The old Libertine package, which worked with pdfTeX, included a command `\libertineGlyph{}`. `\libertineGlyph{Fourroman}` printed

> Ⅳ

But how can I get these roman numbers used for numbering sections and even in the TOC?

I found [Using ligatures from libertine for roman numerals in pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79862/using-ligatures-from-libertine-for-roman-numerals-in-pdftex) , but I do not know how to make it work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
 \usepackage{libertine}


\newcommand*{\libertineRoman}[1]{%
    \def\Romantemp{}%
    \ifnum\value{#1}>0\relax%
        \ifnum\value{#1}<13\relax%
            \edef\Romantemp{\ifcase\value{#1}\or One\or Two\or Three\or Four\or Five\or Six\or Seven\or Eight\or Nine\or Ten\or Eleven\or Twelve\fi}%
            \libertineGlyph{\Romantemp roman}%
        \else\Roman{#1}\fi%
    \else\Roman{#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand*{\libertineroman}[1]{%
    \def\Romantemp{}%
    \ifnum\value{#1}>0\relax%
        \ifnum\value{#1}<13\relax%
            \edef\Romantemp{\ifcase\value{#1}\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\fi}%
            \libertineGlyph{\Romantemp roman}%
        \else\roman{#1}\fi%
    \else\roman{#1}\fi%
}


%%% Roman numbers
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

%%% Roman ligatures from Linux Libertine?
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\libertineRoman{section}}
%%% DOES NOT WORK


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

{\libertineGlyph{Fourroman}} 

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Cave: I use the old libertine package from years ago, which provides \libertineGlyph for pdfTeX. However, maybe somebody can give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) package also provides `\libertineGlyph` if XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used. This made it possible for me to come up with a solution without installing the old package. The code should also work for the old package.

A counter representation command such as `\arabic` should be expandable if you don't want to run into troubles. Your commands are not expandable, though.

Below I define five commands:

- `\LibertineRomanByName{<name>}` -- a shortcut for `\libertineGlyph{<name>roman}`.
- `\LibertineUCRomanByInt{<integer>}` -- gives the uppercase libertine glyph for the given integer (as long as the integer is in the range of 1--12).
- `\LibertineLCRomanByInt{<integer>}` -- gives the lowercase libertine glyph for the given integer (as long as the integer is in the range of 1--12).
- `\lbtRoman{<counter>}` -- gives the uppercase libertine glyph for the corresponding counter value or the usual result of `\Roman` if the counter is out of range.
- `\lbtroman{<counter>}` -- gives the lowercase libertine glyph for the corresponding counter value or the usual result of `\roman` if the counter is out of range.

The Code

```
Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\setcounter{section}{7}
Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\setcounter{section}{13}
Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\LibertineUCRomanByInt{1} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{1}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{2} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{2}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{3} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{3}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{4} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{4}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{5} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{5}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{6} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{6}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{7} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{7}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{8} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{8}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{9} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{9}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{10} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{10}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{11} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{11}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{12} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{11}

\setcounter{section}{7}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\lbtRoman{section}}
\section{Let's see: it works!}
```

then gives

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\LibertineRomanByName[1]{\libertineGlyph{#1roman}}
\newcommand*\LibertineUCRomanByInt[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{One}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Two}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Three}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Four}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Five}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Six}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Seven}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Eight}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Nine}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Ten}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Eleven}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{Twelve}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*\LibertineLCRomanByInt[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{one}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{two}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{three}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{four}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{five}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{six}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{seven}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{eight}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{nine}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{ten}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{eleven}%
  \or\LibertineRomanByName{twelve}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*\lbtRoman[1]{\expandafter\@lbtRoman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@lbtRoman[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    0%
  \else
    \ifnum#1<13
      \LibertineUCRomanByInt{#1}%
    \else
      \@Roman{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand*\lbtroman[1]{\expandafter\@lbtroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@lbtroman[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    0%
  \else
    \ifnum#1<13
      \LibertineLCRomanByInt{#1}%
    \else
      \@roman{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\setcounter{section}{7}
Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\setcounter{section}{13}
Uppercase: \lbtRoman{section}, lowercase: \lbtroman{section}

\LibertineUCRomanByInt{1} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{1}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{2} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{2}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{3} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{3}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{4} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{4}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{5} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{5}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{6} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{6}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{7} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{7}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{8} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{8}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{9} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{9}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{10} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{10}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{11} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{11}\par
\LibertineUCRomanByInt{12} \LibertineLCRomanByInt{11}

\setcounter{section}{7}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\lbtRoman{section}}
\section{Let's see: it works!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although my example does not use `\tableofcontents` it would work with it, too.

Comment: Whoo! Worx perfectly, with pdfLaTeX and TOC! I'll test it in real life documents and will report, if there were any issue. However: Thank you very much!

Comment: @KeksDose you're welcome :)