# How to make page numbering with ligature roman style?

Tags: numbering, ligatures, front-matter, roman

I use roman page number for front matter, I was just wondering, is it possible to make these roman numbers as ligature?

See.

Roman:

[image]

and

[image]

roman:

[image]

Comment: Does this question help? [Roman numerals with over and underline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/roman-numerals-with-over-and-underline) Also related: [Using Unicode Roman numerals in XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/using-unicode-roman-numerals-in-xetex/38702#38702)

Comment: @egreg: Unicode suggests to not use the Unicode roman characters; see the comments for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38695/using-unicode-roman-numerals-in-xetex/38702#38702

Comment: I added the codes mentioned in " Roman numerals with over and underline" and use： \pagenumbering{barroman}. It turned out not working. It only works in text mode. @ Martin Schröder: I also tried the codes you provided, it seems work, the the page number is like 'âĚř
'.

Comment: @egreg I agree it is related. However, your solution seems not to be expandable. Do you think the questions should be merged? I suppose not, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This introduces two new numberings: `xroman` and `xRoman`, that try to do what you want. We had to introduce our own for-cycle, because we have to make everything expandable. In the result, we just add a negative space between the letters. We use small-caps for the lower-case variant, and we use a trick with a robust command to add the dot on `i`.

**EDIT:** The new version works with `hyperref` package without causing warnings.

**EDIT 2:** The new version allows horizontal adjustments of the dot over `i`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagenumbering{xroman}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand \i@xroman{\rlap{\kern-0.007em\.{}}i}
\def \@xroman@for #1#2\@nil{\if i#1\i@xroman\else#1\fi\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\hskip-0.093em\@xroman@for#2\@nil\fi}
\def \@xRoman@for #1#2\@nil{\uppercase{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else\hskip-0.09em\@xRoman@for#2\@nil\fi}
\newcommand \@Xroman [1]{\begingroup\scshape\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@xroman@for\@roman{#1}\relax\@nil\endgroup}
\newcommand \@XRoman [1]{\begingroup        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@xRoman@for\@roman{#1}\relax\@nil\endgroup}
\newcommand \xroman [1]{\expandafter\@xroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand \xRoman [1]{\expandafter\@xRoman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{
  \let\@xroman\@Xroman
  \let\@xRoman\@XRoman
}{
  \newcommand \@xroman [1]{\texorpdfstring{\@Xroman{#1}}{\@roman{#1}}}
  \newcommand \@xRoman [1]{\texorpdfstring{\@XRoman{#1}}{\@Roman{#1}}}
}}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{3678}

\section{ABC}\label{abc}

This is Section \ref{abc} on page \pageref{abc}.

hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to use this code for front matter page numbering? \pagenumbering{xroman} seems not working. Also i tried \setcounter{page}{3} in the front matter codes, it shows still like "iii".

Comment: It really worked out, perfect!  By the way, using this code with pdflatex in texmaker, it takes much longer time (100% CPU...) than in Terminal (very fast).

Comment: There is another minor issue, when using \pagenumbering{xroman} or {xRoman}, hyperref warning info:

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\uppercase' on input line 53.
....
I know this is like using Greek symbol in Hyperref, and hence the warning inform arose.

Comment: @KOF Noticed, improved ;)