# Offset in page numbers in pdf viewer due to roman numbering of frontmatter makes printing difficult

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, viewers, printing

My PDF document generated with LaTeX has roman numbering for the frontmatter.

My problem is: if I want to print a certain range of pages, it is very difficult to select them, because my PDF Viewer (`Skim.app` or `Preview.app` in `MacOS X 10.6.8`) seems to count the pages from the beginning of the PDF (1 = first page of PDF), but it displays the correct page numbers of the document (so page 1 is the first page of the mainmatter).

Is there a way to solve this so that the page numbers displayed are the same like those I have to enter in the printing dialog?

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\section{Here starts the Frontmatter}
text frontmatter

\mainmatter

\section{here starts the mainmatter}

text mainmatter: in my PDF viewer this is page 1, but when I would like to print it, I'd have to print page 3 (selecting page 1 in the print dialog would print page i, the first page of the PDF)

\backmatter

\section{here comes the backmatter}
text backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible (I'll look into it and post an answer), but it is certainly really tricky.

Comment: Does Adobe Reader have the correct page numbers? I'm pretty sure I've seen Reader take different numbering schemes into account.

Comment: I do not know about Adobe Reader (can’t test here) but both [Foxit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TGnwv.png) and [SumatraPDF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWYEv.png) show both numbers, the _TeX_ number (i, ii, 1, 2, 3) and the _PDF_ number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). (In SumatraPDF you can even type “ii” to get to the second _PDF_ page.) Though you still have to choose the _PDF_ number to select the printing range.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel + Torbjørn T.: thanks a lot! Your comment helped me finding the solution (see my answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89192/4009 )

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Acrobat shows the "text" page numbers and uses them in the print dialog as well, so never dare to have two pages with the same number (`2` and `ii` is ok, but `ii` and `ii` is not). Another problem might be with a page that accidentally has _no_ page number at all.

Comment: @tohecz: Seems like a serious bug in AR: The labels are just labels and every page can have the same or none. Viewers must cope with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of Qrrbrbirlbel Torbjørn T. and  I found the solution myself:

`Skim.app` (version 1.3.22) indeed displays both page numbers (example for first page of MWE):

[image]

- it shows page "i" in the white box on the left
- and it shows page "1 of 5" (the *"real"* page, starting by 1 for the first page) in the title bar of the window

`Preview.app` (version 5.0.1.) only displays the "real" page number (first page of PDF = 1) in the title bar

So in both applications if I choose the "real" page number from the title bar in the printing dialog, I can precisely select the page range to print.

Comment: This works similarly in Evince and Okular on Linux -- the viewer displays e.g. "`ii (4 of 12)`".

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this in your preamble. We use `\EveryShipout` to step our new counter `xpage` with every shipped page, then we use `\texorpdfstring` to write something different in text and in PDF comments. In the PDF comments we write this number. The modification of `\pagenumbering` ensures that our modified numbering is used correctly everywhere.

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{everyshi}
\newcounter{xpage}\stepcounter{xpage}
\def\@xnumber#1#2{\texorpdfstring{#1{#2}}{\@arabic\c@xpage}}
\def\@xroman{\@xnumber{\@roman}} % repeat for every numbering style you use
\def\@xRoman{\@xnumber{\@Roman}} % repeat for every numbering style you use
\def\@xarabic{\@xnumber{\@arabic}} % repeat for every numbering style you use
\let\@xpagenumbering\pagenumbering
\def\pagenumbering#1{\@xpagenumbering{x#1}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\EveryShipout{\stepcounter{xpage}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! Could your code have any side-effects on other things or features?  I'm sorry, I found a simple solution to my printing problem myself (see my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89192/4009 )

Comment: @Martin It should work properly, I use a similar trick elsewhere myself: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88398/how-to-make-page-numbering-with-ligature-roman-style

Comment: The `count1to` package defines a counter for the physical page number (and solves this problem for DVIs).