# Roman numerals in sans serif fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, sans-serif, roman-numerals

<sub>Inspired by a question, that unfortunately has been deleted by the OP after getting some hints from me in a comment.</sub>

Lacking serifs the Roman numerals in sans serif fonts look sometimes a bit strange. Do you have some ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest the package `romanbar`. This produces Roman numerals with an over- and an underline, and without serifs.

The basic command for this is `\Romanbar{⟨arabic number⟩}`, this works also with counters inside! You can instead include a Roman numeral, as well. For more abilities see example file of package documentation.

An example (*note, in KOMA-Script all titles are by default printed in sans serif fonts*):

```
\documentclass[numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{romanbar}

\begin{document}

\section{section I vs. \Romanbar{\thesection}}
MDCLXVI vs. \Romanbar{1666}.

\stepcounter{section}
\section{section III vs. \Romanbar{\thesection}}
MDCLXVI vs. \Romanbar{MDCLXVI}.

\setcounter{section}{1665}
\section{section MDCLXVI vs. \Romanbar{\thesection}}
2014 vs. \Romanbar{2014} vs. \Romanbar{\relax 2014}.

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

This package is BTW based on [egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24084) to a question here on TeX.SE: [Roman numerals with over- and underline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24065/roman-numerals-with-over-and-underline) (the OP [Stephen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen) is also the package author).