# Roman numeral with Subscript

Tags: subscripts, roman-numerals

I'm trying to enter Roman numerals with subscripts, but doing `$II_1$` is not working, as the II ends up being spaced out.

Is there any way to add a subscript, while making the Roman numeral elegant? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simple case is, as in comment, $\textrm{II}_1$. If you need use it many times, a macro may be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{myRom}
\newcounter{myarab}
\def\Rns#1#2{\setcounter{myRom}{#1}
\setcounter{myarab}{#2}\Roman{myRom}$_{\arabic{myarab}}$}

\Rns{3}{3}

\Rns{2016}{13}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is as a result of the letters being considered as *factors* in a *multiplication*. Since `I` in your case has a different meaning, you need to set it differently.

Below is a couple of macros that converts an integer to a roman numeral (`\toroman` or `\toRoman`) or sets it as `\text` (using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) so it works in text or math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\toroman}[1]{\text{\romannumeral #1}}
\newcommand{\toRoman}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\toroman{#1}}}
\newcommand{\setRoman}{\text}

\begin{document}

Either \toroman{2016} or \toRoman{2016} and also $\toroman{2016}_1$ and $\toRoman{2016}_1$.
Finally, $\setRoman{II}_2$ is different from $\setRoman{mmxi}_3$.

\end{document}
```

Conversion from roman numerals to integer is also possible, if needed, using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). Also, if you wish to change the representation of the Roman numerals, consider reading [Roman numerals with over- and underline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24065/5764).