# How can I write fancy-looking Roman numerals?

Tags: fonts, roman-numerals

Is there a way to produce Roman numerals in the text in a way that there is an "overline and underline" connected? I have tried using combinations like

```
\overline{\underline{XVI}}
```

but the lines are disconnected. I'm looking a solution that produces similar numerals to the picture below.

[image: Fancy numerals]

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24065/4427 ?

Comment: I didn't see it, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcounter{tmpctr}
\newcommand\fancyRoman[1]{%
  \setcounter{tmpctr}{#1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\kern.2pt\textsf{\Roman{tmpctr}}}%
  \setstackgap{S}{-.6pt}%
  \Shortstack{\rule{\dimexpr\wd0+.1ex}{.7pt}\\\copy0\\
              \rule{\dimexpr\wd0+.1ex}{.7pt}}%
}
\begin{document}
Fancy Romans:

1--5: \fancyRoman{1}
\fancyRoman{2}
\fancyRoman{3}
\fancyRoman{4}
\fancyRoman{5}

6--10: \fancyRoman{6}
\fancyRoman{7}
\fancyRoman{8}
\fancyRoman{9}
\fancyRoman{10}

11--12: \fancyRoman{11}
\fancyRoman{12}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but often it's expected that the roman numerals use the "usual" text roman font, not sans serif.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Understood, except the OP's figure indicated otherwise.  So I went with it.

Comment: Works well. Nice use of the counter! If one already knows they want 'XVI', one could remove the counter and replace the argument for \textsf by #1.

Comment: @Zeick That is correct, if you preferred to enter the roman numeral rather than the arabic numeral as input.

Answer (score 6):

I have used, instead, an old package called [`romanbar`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/romanbar/romanbar.pdf) package to write roman numbers where you can see also the macro of the user @egreg that it is the same of the link of the comment below the question,

[image]

Here there is my small code:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{newtxtext}%%%%%%%%%%%% <----optional (it gives a best view of the roman numbers) - 
%%%% You can choose another font compilable with pdfLaTeX
    \usepackage{romanbar}
    \begin{document}
    \Romanbar{1}, \Romanbar{2}, \Romanbar{5}, \Romanbar{10}, \Romanbar{43}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: First time, I came to know about the package `romanbar`... It is interesting.... Thanks for sharing...

Comment: @MadyYuvi you are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{newtxtext}  
      % <----optional (it gives a best view of the roman numbers) - 
      % You can choose another font compilable with pdfLaTeX
    \usepackage{romanbar}
    \begin{document}
    \Romanbar{1}, \Romanbar{2}, \Romanbar{5}, \Romanbar{10}, \Romanbar{43}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from a previous answer from Sebastiano?