# How to write the Roman numeral "2" in the following form?

Tags: roman-numerals

There seem to be several forms of Roman numerals (I'm not sure which is the most used, the most standardized).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@} 
\begin{document} 
\Rmnum{2} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like to express II in the following form.
[image]

How to handle it?

Comment: How far do you need to go with those funny roman numerals?  More precisely, are the numbers from 1 to 9 sufficient, or you might need 29 for example?

Comment: One more question: What is your text general font?

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps this question is repeated (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528122/how-can-i-write-fancy-looking-roman-numerals.) I just saw the  link. I am using the standard font of tex.

Comment: So now the only thing I'm confused about is which of these two ways of writing is more formal.

Comment: Hi!  Well, on that page, it is not exactly what you are asking for.  In yyour question, the I is serif and V is not.  My first question was pointing in this direction.  It is really what you need?  And if yes, till what roman number?

Comment: Thank you very much for your careful reply. My concern at the time was how the two I's were linked together (to reprensent roman number 2). I didn't pay much attention to the font (serif or other). The second picture is a screenshot I took on the web to illustrate my question. Your reminder also caught my interest. If I need to do this, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is a minimal solution, as the text in the image indicates.  To have a general command, some more work is needed---"general" meaning for numbers <= 35.

**Remark.** The command `\rnum` is there in case some development follows.  Otherwise, one can simply write `I` instead of `rnum{1}` and so on.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\rnum}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\newcommand{\rnumsf}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\textsf{\romannumeral #1}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
You can obtain something like this for particular cases (working each
case separately):
\rnum{1}\hspace{-.7pt}\rnum{1},
\rnum{1}\hspace{-.7pt}\rnum{1}\hspace{-1pt}\rnum{1},
\rnum{1}\rnumsf{5}.

\end{document}
```