# Problem with babel + Greek and endnote package

Tags: numbering, babel, greek, endnotes, roman

I am typesetting a document which includes both French text (the main language) and some Greek. It's a kind of scholarly work and I would like to have both footnotes and endnotes. I would like to use Roman numerals for the endnote counters, rather than letters, since there may be more than 26 of them.

The problem is that it throws an error when I set the endnote counter to Roman numerals with Greek as part of the babel package. At least, as far as I can tell, this is what is happening; I'm probably not seeing what is really going on. Below is a MWE which produces the problem; if `greek` is removed from `babel`'s option list, the error goes away.

Could someone help me see what I'm missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\roman{endnote}}

\begin{document}

tester\endnote{tester}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: There may be some helpful ideas from the answers presented in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/how-can-i-get-roman-numerals-in-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `greek` option to `babel` modifies the `\roman` and `\@roman` commands so that they're independent of the current language; doing so, however, breaks the usage with `endnote`.

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\textlatin} % make \textlatin legal in \edef
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\roman{endnote}}

\begin{document}

tester\endnote{tester}

\textgreek{aaabbbccc\endnote{\textgreek{dddeeefff}}}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]