# Changing endnote mark to roman with babel Greek in TeXLive '17

Tags: babel, endnotes, texlive-2017

Essentially, it is the same problem as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254558/problem-with-babel-greek-and-endnote-package).

I am using footnotes and endnotes together, so I want to change endnotes to roman. The solution given when the question was asked two years ago was to add

```
\robustify{\textlatin}
```

to the preamble, so it would look like

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{endnotes, etoolbox}

\robustify{\textlatin} 
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\roman{endnote}}

\begin{document}

Once\endnote{Or maybe twice} upon a time $t\ge0\ldots$.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

This works in my TeXLive '15 environment, but doesn't work if I use TeXLive '17.

I get a message

```
./text.tex:11: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line
11. <inserted text>
               \fi l.11 Once\endnote{Or maybe twice}
                                                     upon a time $t\ge0\ldots$.
```

Any idea on how can I make it work with TeXLive '17?
I use MacTex, macOS 10.13.2.

Answer (score 1):

Robustify also `\ensureascii`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{endnotes, etoolbox}

\robustify{\textlatin}
\AtBeginDocument{\robustify{\ensureascii}}
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\roman{endnote}}

\begin{document}

Once\endnote{Or maybe twice} upon a time $t\ge0\ldots$.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\textlatin` macro is no longer used in the context of `\roman`, so probably robustifying it is not needed, but it doesn't harm either.

Answer (score 0):

You can by pass some of the expansion problems by using `\romannumeral` directly on the counter value

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[greek,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{endnotes, etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\romannumeral\value{endnote}}

\begin{document}

Once\endnote{Or maybe twice} upon a time $t\ge0\ldots$\endnote{Really twice}.

\textgreek{aaabbbccc\endnote{\textgreek{dddeeefff}}}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```