# datetime2: future dates in a specific (ad hoc) format

Tags: datetime2

I've seen these posts ...

- [Changing date format in datetime2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477319/changing-date-format-in-datetime2)
- [latex date calculations with datetime2 and ddmm format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453522/latex-date-calculations-with-datetime2-and-ddmm-format)

... and in theory I ought to be knowing what to do, yet... I am not. Instead... I'm lost!

I **don't** want to change the general Format of the way the date is beeing displayed (that for the 1st example), but I do want to get a Future date (in 5 days), but **not** in the Format I get from the 2nd example.

So if today is **June 29th of 2020** (ISO 2020-06-29) and I want the date **5 days in the future** I should get july 4th (I see I can do this with datetime2), **but be able to format the ouput ad hoc** and not change it for the whole document.

Now I would like to be able to have (in abstract) something like this:

```
\offsetdate{opffset}{dateformat}{seperator}
```

... respectivly to do like this:

```
\offsetdate{5}{ddmmyyyy}{.}
```

to get 05.07.2020

```
\offsetdate{5}{dmyyyy}{.}
```

to get 5.7.2020

```
\offsetdate{5}{yyyymmdd}{}
```

to plainly get 20200704

**Any hints will be *greatly* appreciated!**

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152392/date-format-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: did the answer suit your requirement

Answer (score 1):

from --

http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/texdate/texdate.pdf

and  --

[Date format: YYYY-MM-DD](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152392/date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{texdate}
\begin{document}
%\initcurrdate
%\printfdate{ISOext}

\initdate{2019}{6}{24}
\printfdate{ISO}
\printfdate{ISOext}\par 

\advancebydays{8}
8 days later: \printfdate{ISO}\par
\end{document}
```

**Addendum -- with reference to the OP example requirement of 29 Jun 2020**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{texdate}
\begin{document}

\initdate{2020}{6}{29}
\advancebydays{5}

5 days later: 

|ISO date|:\printfdate{ISO}\par

\def\setdateformat{d\ B\ Y}
|d\ B\ Y|: \printdate\par
\def\setdateformat{d.m.Y}
|d.m.Y|: \printdate\par
\def\setdateformat{a,\ d\ b\ Y}
|a,\ d\ b\ Y|: \printdate\par
\printfdate{ISOext}\par
\end{document}
```