# How to generate a roman numbers symbol in this font/style/format?

Tags: roman-numerals

this [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23487/195238)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Charles's sister Bona, married the eldest son of Philip \rom{6} of France,
the future John \rom{2} of France, in 1335.

Today is the year \rom{2011}.
\end{document}
```

generates this roman numbers symbol

[image]

how to generate the roman numbers symbol in this font/style/format?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a `\mathbb{I}`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{I}$
\end{document} `

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `\mathbb{I}` that ships with `amsfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[ p(h|\mathcal{D})=
\frac{p(h|\mathcal{D})p(h)}{\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{H}} p(h'|\mathcal{D})}=
\frac{p(h)\mathbb{I}(\mathcal{D}\in h)/|h|^N}{%
\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{H}} p(h')\mathbb{I}(\mathcal{D}\in h')/|h'|^N}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It *could* also be a `\mathbbm{I}` that requires the `bbm` package.